# PhoneGap and Highcharts

Tags: javascript, cordova, highcharts

I'm working on hybrid mobile application (Cordova-Phonegap) with Highcharts and I'm querying data from database and trying to display data dynamically on chart.

This is the code that gets the data and this works.

```
var exerciseData = [];//global
var chart;//global
```

EDIT 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //chart is here
}

//Cordova is ready               
  function onDeviceReady() {   
  db.transaction(queryDB);
}
```

// Query the database

```
function queryDB(tx) {
      //get all results from db
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MYTABLE', [], querySuccess, errorCB); 
 } 

function querySuccess(tx, results) {

          var len = results.rows.length;
          console.log("MYTABLE table: " + len + " rows found.");

          for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
              console.log("Row = " + i + " Reading_name = " + results.rows.item(i).Reading_name + " Date="+results.rows.item(i).Rec_date + " Reading =  " + results.rows.item(i).Reading);

           //get exercise data only
           if(results.rows.item(i).Reading_name=='exercise'){

               var reading=parseInt(results.rows.item(i).Reading);
               var thisDate=results.rows.item(i).Rec_date;

               var exObj=([manageDate(thisDate), reading]);
               exerciseData.push(exObj);     
              }

           } 
          }
```

Now, when I take `exerciseData` and set it as follows:

```
chart.series[0].setData(exerciseData,true);
```

then nothing gets displayed on the chart.

But If I set it as:

```
chart.series[0].setData([[1383824000000,10] ],true);
```

then I can see the datapoint on the chart.

How can I fix the `exerciseData` array to display data on Highchart chart series?

`console.log(exObj);` displays:

```
[1363996800000, 10]
```

and `console.log(exerciseData);` gives me this:

```
[
Array[2]
0: 1363996800000
1: 10
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

Edit:
chart code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

             chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                },
                title: {

                    text: 'chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    labels: {
                             formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.value);
                            },
                                dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                                        minute: '%H:%M',
                                        hour: '%H:%M',
                                        day: '%e. %b',
                                        week: '%e. %b',
                                        month: '%b \'%y',
                                        year: '%Y'
                                    }
                           } 

                },
                yAxis: {

                   title: {
                      text: ''
                    },
                      min: 0
                },

                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Exercise',
                        data: [],
                        type:'spline'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'MyData2',
                        data: [],
                        type:'line'
                    });

            chart.series[0].setData(exerciseData,true);//does not work
            chart.series[1].setData([[1383824000000,10]],true);

          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var exObj=[];
exObj.push(manageDate(thisDate));
exObj.push(reading);
exerciseData.push(exObj);
```

Another way is to specify the point using x,y e.g.

```
var exObj = {
    x:manageDate(thisDate),
    y:reading
}
```

Also, you need to call

```
chart.series[0].setData(exerciseData,true
```

Inside your success function.

Comment: What does console.log look like for exercise data using my code?

Comment: Your first code gives exactly the same as mine: [
Array[2]
0: 1364083200000
1: 12
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
] Second one just replaces 0 and 1 with x and y.

Comment: Try reversing the ads. Maybe it's something to do with line/spline

Comment: line and spline don't seem to interfere. I think exerciseData doesn't get data in right format because when I set it globally as exerciseData=[[1383824000000,10],[1623824000000,12]]; then it works.

Comment: There was a typo in my first code example. Try again? Also, what does console.log show for the code in your previous comment?

Comment: I noticed the typo-not the issue. Console.log gives the same result for exerciseData whether it's global or in querySuccess-not formatting then. querySuccess is callback function, can this make difference? I've added EDIT 2 on top of my question.

Comment: Are you callingchartsetseries inside your success callback?

Comment: No I wasn't and that was the problem, once I moved  chart.series[0].setData(exerciseData,true); to querySuccess, it works. Thanks for your patience and help.